# How to send files from NAND Flash(connected to a microcontroller) to PC?

Tags: stm32, microcontroller, spi, microprocessors

I have data stored of sensors in NAND flash using SPI Protocol with STM32H743 IC in file format(.txt)(multiple files are created in NAND flash).

I want to take out that data from NAND flash and send it to my PC for analysis.

How should I transfer this data?

We have already stored data in NAND flash, we are struggling to send data to the PC as we are not able to find a way to transfer files from SPI.

We are using a USB Connection to connect to the PC.
There is no other use of the USB.
We are only using 1 SPI connection for sensor data and 1 SPI for NAND Flash memory.

The USB connection is a serial device,we are not using this port to upload the code or something else, we had planned to send data through this port to the CPU,which is not happening for now.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What connections do you have between your microcontroller and your PC?

Comment: We have a USB connection

Comment: And what do you do with this USB connection, aside from having a potential channel to send files? (Since you took the [tour], you surely noticed that you are supposed to [edit] your question with new information. Do not add a comment, this is not a forum.)

Comment: What kind of USB connection is this? Is it a serial device? Is it something proprietary to upload your program only? Please note that we need anything to work with. The possibilities are endless, and recommendations are off-topic here on SO.